# Why does this code sort of work?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I started writing this code a few days ago. I saw a question on here that got me wondering about variable argument lists, so I wrote (never really finished, but it has the functionality I was curious about) this piece of code:

```
void VendingMachine::setStamps(int largest, ...)
{
   cout << "Setting stamps to: \n";
   vector<int> tmp;
   vector<int>::iterator iter;
   int next = largest;
   va_list lst;
   va_start(lst, largest);
   while(next != NULL)
   {
      cout << next << "\n";
      tmp.push_back(next);
      next = va_arg(lst,int);
   }
   va_end(lst);

   stamps = new int[tmp.size()-1];

   int i = 0;
   for(iter = tmp.begin(); iter != tmp.end();)
   {
      stamps[i] = *iter;
      iter++;
      i++;
   }

   cout << "The array is now: ";
   showStamps();
}

void VendingMachine::showStamps()
{
   cout << sizeof(stamps) << " " << sizeof(*stamps);
   for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF(stamps); i++)
      cout << stamps[i] << ", ";
   cout << "\n";
}
```

Now, what I'd expect is for setStamps to never finish. Or at least take a very long time, and a variable amount of time, since no part of the list is guaranteed to be NULL unless it was supplied. This isn't the case. I call setStamps with `v.setStamps(90,30,24,15,12,10,5,3,2,1);` and it prints this out:

> Setting stamps to:
>   90
>   30
>   24
>   15
>   12
>   10
>   5
>   3
>   2
>   1
>   -217832717
>   The array is now: 4 490,

Ignoring the last line, since that was me messing around trying to figure out how to determine the length of an array, this doesn't make sense. It stopped after the first value that was outside of the passed arguments. It should have kept going until there was a NULL value, and there shouldn't be one of those in the same place each time. But the outcome is always the same: 90, 30, 24, 15, 12, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1, [number that changes each time]. There's never any additional values. It's a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and there shouldn't be one of those in the same place each time

Who says there won't be one in the same place every time? The behavior is undefined, and so having a NULL value in the same place every time is entirely possible.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's just reaching into undeclared memory, so a NULL value is possible but shouldn't be consistently in the same place. I really know nothing about the stdarg library though, so it may have been done in such a way that this happens either purposely or as a side effect of however it was programmed.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, the memory you are accessing is on the stack. This can be highly deterministic based on the surrounding code that you've written. And its entirely possible that some other code you wrote is actually putting that NULL value in that exact place on the stack.

Comment: @demize Undefined behavior is allowed to be consistent. The line `next = va_arg(lst,int)` has undefined behavior when called after the last argument has been retrieved. It might be reaching into uninitialized memory, or memory that happens to get consistently set by some previously run, unrelated code, or it might detect that there are no more arguments and return NULL, or the program's output might be "Hello, World!". The behavior is undefined. Asking why it behaves a particular way is pointless in the context of C++.

Comment: va_arg cannot determine whether it's hit the last argument or not. You need another way to infer the number of arguments. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_arg/

Comment: @Pete855217 It's not defined to do so, but there's no reason an implementation couldn't stick type info and argument counts somewhere when it makes a vararg call.

Comment: @barnes53 I think that's what I meant: there's nothing inherent in va_arg to identify argument count, but you have to actively provide it somewhere eg. in the function call. Have I got that right?

Comment: @Pete855217 What I mean is that an implementations could provide the information to itself. When the compiler sees `foo(1,2,3)` for a function declared `void foo(...)` the implementation could store somewhere "three arguments of type int, int, int". And then when the program tries to access a fourth argument, va_arg could check that information, see there's no fourth argument, and return NULL. This behavior would conform with the requirements for vararg functions.

Comment: @bames53 But that's not what it does. You call `foo(1,2,3)` and it gives you four arguments instead of three. If something is going to make it return NULL then it makes the most sense to do it when there are no arguments.
It seems most likely to me that it's just that I'm reaching somewhere that has a NULL value already, but nothing in my code is set to a NULL value except for `i` in for loops.

Comment: @demize I'm not saying your implementation does that, I only mean that that would be conforming behavior, since the behavior is undefined. Yes, the behavior you're getting indicates that you are just happening to find NULL. Your code doesn't need to be the one setting that value anywhere either. Lots of memory locations get consistently set to all kinds of values just as a result of things the implementation does behind the scenes.